# in the/their hundreds

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Which word is correct in the following?

> Tourists arrived in **the/their** hundreds.

> People flocked in **the/their** thousands to see her.

> The region attracts tourists in **the/their** multitudes.

The second and third sentences come from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/in_1?q=in

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/multitude?q=multitude

Comment: I would use either _in hundreds/thousands_ or _in their hundreds/thousands_. I don't think you can use _multitudes_ in the same way, because it isn't an estimate of the size of the crowd. Just say _multitudes of tourists_.

Comment: Where's the research and what's the context? I mean how did this problem appear to you?

Comment: The second and third sentences come from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/in_1?q=in

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/multitude?q=multitude

Comment: A Canadian says he'd use "in the hundreds" for the first one.

Comment: @KateBunting - I have a love/hate relationship with Andrew Lloyd Webber (i.e. I profess to hate all his works, and only listen to them in secret), and in _Les Miserables_ there is a song 'Stars' - Stars/ In your multitudes/ Scarce to be counted/ Filling the darkness / With order and light!/ You are the sentinels/ Silent and sure/ Keeping watch in the night (&c.)

Comment: SING, goddess, the anger of Peleus’ son Achilleus
and its devastation, which put pains thousandfold upon the Achaians,
hurled in their multitudes to the house of Hades strong souls
of heroes, but gave their bodies to be the delicate feasting
of dogs' - Homer _The Iliad_ Translation by Richmond Lattimore Chicago 1951

Comment: I conclude, a bit old fashioned maybe, or poetic ('in their multitudes').

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - OK, I stand corrected. It just seemed a rather odd usage to me.

Comment: @KateBunting - well, I must correct myself, too, because Andrew Lloyd Webber had nothing to do with _Les Mis_. The music was by  Claude-Michel Schönberg, and the English lyrics were by Herbert Kretzmer.